# How to sort table data by date?

Tags: angular, typescript, material-table

This is my data table

[image: DataTable]
as you can see on the table, the oldest registration date is on top, but I want the newest data to be on top.

Here is my code:

```
this.dataSource = [];
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.createdAt > b.createdAt) {
          return 1;
        }
      if (a.createdAt < b.createdAt) {
          return -1;
        }
      return 0;

    });
```

`createdAt` is a string

Comment: what is the value inside `createdAt` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting code is incorrect. The Correct sorting code is:

```
this.dataSource = [];
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.sort((a, b) => {
      var result = 0;
      if (a.createdAt > b.createdAt) {
          result = 1;
      } else {
          result = -1;
      }
      return result;
    });
```

Comment: @RenceSacramento Please check the format of createdAt variable since it is a string and the comparison works for date format only.

Answer (score 0):

@Rence Sacramento **createdAt** would be timestamp or date string.
Also, it would be two different variables "DataSource" and "dataSource".

```
this.DataSource = [];  
    this.DataSource = this.dataSource.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(a.createdAt) - new Date(b.createdAt); // ASC order by createdAt
    });
```